# How do I grab the nick of each member instead of the whole member object? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord

Here is my code:

```py
#This will take three random members from a list of mentions and add them to a team
@bot.command(name="team")
async def team(ctx: commands.Context, players: commands.Greedy[discord.Member]):
    ''': Get 3 random members from a list'''
    random_player = random.sample(players, 3)
    print(random_player)
    await ctx.send(f"Team A: {random_player.nick}")
```

However the output gives me way too much info:

```
[<Member id=**************** name='personA' discriminator='****' bot=False nick='Spag Eddie' guild=<Guild id=**************** name='myDiscordServer' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=34>>, <Member id=**************** name='personB' discriminator='****' bot=False nick='Señor' guild=<Guild id=**************** name='myDiscordServer' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=34>>, <Member id=**************** name='personC' discriminator='****' bot=False nick='CaptainCrack' guild=<Guild id=**************** name='myDiscordServer' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=34>>]
```

I tried adding a 'nick' attribute to the f-string in the final line:

```
await ctx.send(f"Team A: {random_player.nick}")
```

But this gave me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 19, in team
    await ctx.send(f"Team A: {random_player.nick}")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'nick'
```

I am not sure how to grab just the nick of each member instead of the whole member object.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're trying to get the `nick` from a `list` of Members, not from a specific Member. Because of this, you are getting an error that `list` does not have `nick`.

If you're trying to get a list of nicknames separated by commas, you can do this:

```py
members = ...
nicknames = [memb.nick for memb in members]
nicknames_comma_sep = ", ".join(nicknames)
await ctx.send(f"Team A: {nicknames_comma_sep}")
```

Answer (score 0):

*Moved from an edit to the question by the OP to an answer.*

`random_player` is a `list` and not a `Member`. What you want is this:

```py
await ctx.send(f"Team A: {[player.mention for player in random_player]}")
```